# Pockets shading

Tags: cloth-simulation

I want to create pockets on a pants with the cloth simulation modifier.
I need the pockets made by polygons and not by using normal maps and not by some other fake methods. I need real pockets for putting hand in it. So when I add some extra polygons above the pants polygons there is some shading difference(see image). How can I fix it, so shade of pants and shade of pockets has smoothed transition?

[image]

Thanks!

Updated(with normals all is ok):
[image]

Updated:
[image]

Comment: I've added image to post, with normals all is ok. I think the reason of different shading is two polygons which connects with one polygon and shades calculates like interpolation between connected polygons. But how to fix it I don't know.

Comment: Add thickness (what you'd have to do anyway) eg. using a solidify modifier and the issue will go away automatically.

Comment: Try Remove Custom Normal or Recalculate ... Or try to split deepest pocket edge ... If doesn't work attach your file via https://blend-exchange.com/ to let us to check. Thank you @brockmann I would say with Solidify you will run into another issue here ...

Comment: @brockmann it has solidify modifier, I just remove it for screenshots for better understanding of topology. And thickness doesn't helps because it doesn't influence on polygon's normal's and shades.

Comment: @vklidu recalculating normals also doesn't helps, I tried to make the pocket from both sides but it cause problems with collisions https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWRaB.png
 I will try custom normals, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got why it happens, by some reason I had checked mark here

[image]

I've unchecked the mark and shades is smoothed now.